# Can we verify (or have ) same domain in Amazon SES from different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have two different AWS account and only one domain server like example.com
Now, I cannot share smtp keys with different account, so how can I configure SES with same domain.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Common Domain Verification Problems - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-verification-problems.html#domain-verification-common-problems

Comment: No, I didn't tried to use same domain in different AWS account as I am not sure my DNS provider "Linode" will support two TXT records and will not impact anything.

Comment: Check it to see. You could use subdomains for each account to divide them.

Comment: What happen if I have one DNS service contain parent domain and route53 contain sub-domain. If team using sub-domain, do some stress testing, in this case will it imapct my parent domain (SES)?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your main question.
Yes you can use the verify the same domain (example.com) from multiple AWS Accounts. (If you have your DNS hosted in R53 then its even easier)

See the following excerpt from Amazon Docs

> **You want to verify the same domain multiple times and you can't have multiple TXT records with the same name**—You might need to verify
>   your domain more than once because you're sending in different regions
>   or you're sending from multiple AWS accounts from the same domain in
>   the same region. If your DNS provider does not allow you to have
>   multiple TXT records with the same name, there are two workarounds.
>   The first workaround, if your DNS provider allows it, is to assign
>   multiple values to the TXT record. For example, if your DNS is managed
>   by Amazon Route 53, you can set up multiple values for the same TXT
>   record as follows:
>
> 1. In the Amazon Route 53 console, choose the
>      _amazonses TXT record you added when you verified your domain in the first region.
> 2. In the Value box, press Enter after the first value.
> 3. Add the value for the additional region, and save the record set.
>
> The
>   other workaround is that if you only need to verify your domain twice,
>   you can verify it once with _amazonses in the TXT record name and the
>   other time you can omit _amazonses from the record name entirely. We
>   recommend the previous solution as a best practice, however.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-verification-problems.html#domain-verification-common-problems

Also for best practice refer the below Doc
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/can-i-use-multiple-aws-accounts-with-ses/

Comment: To answer your question in the comments.
"What happen if I have one DNS service contain parent domain and route53 contain sub-domain. If team using sub-domain, do some stress testing, in this case will it imapct my parent domain (SES)?"

Comment: Normally during stress testing you send out emails to invalid Email IDs, so there is a chance of your account going into suspension for high bounce rate (in this case your test account which uses the sub-domain). The AWS Investigation team can match your main domain (and suspend your main account also.

Comment: So to avoid it follow below suggestions
1. Get a new domain for testing (example.xyz registed it under test SES) - So that your testing will not suspend main account
2. Use valid mailnator email IDs for testing
3. Use SNS to alert if bounce rate is high
4. Use multi-region SES for failover in Main account